# How to get username and uuid by bearer token from keycloak programmaticaly (Spring)?

Tags: java, spring, rest, keycloak

I have Spring application with keycloak dependency.
Front-end send to my back-end bearer token and I want to get username and his UUID from keycloak using this token.

Here is my keycloak configuration.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class,
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.management.HttpSessionManager"))
@EnableWebSecurity
class KeycloakConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMINS")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

And in this endpoint I am getting authorization header:

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/save/{title}")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @PathVariable("title") String title, @RequestHeader("Authorization") String authHeader) {
//get user by token?

    }
```

Comment: Add relevant code with details and error if any

Comment: Controller signature needs to include Principal (+ some more config). Follow [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak) tutorial. That will get you the username for free.

Comment: @identigral in my case works great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Shortly, I do parse public key and access token to get AccessToken class, which has all you need ( accessToken.getId() and accessToken.getPreferredUsername() )

```
@Autowired
private KeycloakSpringBootProperties keycloakProperties;

public String getRealm() {
    return keycloakProperties.getRealm();
}

public String getAuthServerUrl() {
    return keycloakProperties.getAuthServerUrl();
}

public String getRealmUrl() {
    return getAuthServerUrl()
            + "/realms/"
            + getRealm();
}

public String getOpenIdConnectUrl() {
    return getRealmUrl() + "/protocol/openid-connect";
}

public String getOpenIdConnectCertsUrl() {
    return getOpenIdConnectUrl() + "/certs";
}

public AccessToken loadAccessToken(String accessToken) throws TokenNotActiveException, VerificationException, NoSuchFieldException {
    PublicKey publicKey = new KeyCloakRsaKeyLoader().getPublicKeyFromKeyCloak(getOpenIdConnectCertsUrl());
    String realmUrl = keyCloakConnectionProvider.getRealmUrl();
    AccessToken token =
            RSATokenVerifier.verifyToken(
                    accessToken,
                    publicKey,
                    realmUrl,
                    true,
                    true);

    return token;
}
```